# Integral flow that can commute to Laplacian operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Firstly, considering the vector field in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $, $ X=x_2e_1-x_1e_2 $, we can see that
$$
\phi(t,x)=\phi(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)=(t,x_1\cos t+x_2\sin t,-x_1\sin t+x_2\cos t,x_3) 
$$
is the corresponding integral flow. Obviously, it can be verified that
$$
\Delta(f\circ\phi(t,x))=\Delta (f)\circ\phi(t,x),
$$
that is, $ \phi $ commutes to $ \Delta $. This inspired me to consider a question as follows.

> For a smooth vector fields $ X\in T\mathbb{R}^n $, that is, $ X=\sum_{i=1}^nX^i(x)e_i $ with $ X^i(x)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) $, there is a corresponding integral flow $ \phi(t,x) $ (at least exists for $ t\ll 1 $) such that
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{\operatorname{d\!}\phi(t,x)}{\operatorname{d\!}t}=X\big(\phi(t,x)\big),\\
> \phi(0,x)=x.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Now, for what cases, $ \phi(t,x) $ can commute to $ \Delta $. That is
> $$
> \Delta(f\circ\phi(t,x))=\Delta (f)\circ\phi(t,x).
> $$

Here is my try. I firstly consider the rotational vector fields. Obviously all vector fields satisfy the conditions. I also consider vector fields like $ X=(1+x_2)e_1-x_1e_2 $. I find that such $ X $ also generates a integral field commuting to $ \Delta $. I do not know how to go on. Can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: If $B$ is the first order differential operator $B=\sum_i X^i D_{x_i}$ the flow $\phi$ gives the solution of the equation $u_t=Bu$, that is $u(t,x)=f(\phi(t,x))$ solves the equation before with initial datum $f$. The commutativity you are asking for is then equivalent to $\Delta B=B\Delta$.